# Страница 404 частично не переведена

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/%D1%84%D1%8B%D0%B0asdf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, есть такая проблема, давно висит.